# How to do operation on list of numbers?

Tags: python, range

I'm trying to do the [Collatz conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) on a list of numbers to check which one is "holding" the most. the problem is the code keeps telling me "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'"

```
Collatz = range(1, 1001)
counting = 0
print(Collatz)
while Collatz != 1:
    if Collatz % 2 == 0:
        Collatz = int(Collatz / 2)
        print(Collatz)
        counting += 1
    else:
        Collatz = int(Collatz * 3 + 1)
        print(Collatz)
        counting += 1
print(counting)
```

if it's with input it works great...
Would appreciate help :)

try to get a list of all of the ranges, with a number and how long it took to get to "1" or just which one is the longest.
for example:
number 1 took 1 steps to get to "1"
number 2 took 2 steps to get to "1"
number 3 took 8 steps to get to "1" etc

or

number 153 took 736 steps to get to "1" (IDK, just for the example)

Comment: Aren't you meant to be using `number` instead of `Collatz` for your checking inside the `for` ?

Comment: @JonClements I fixed it, it was oneof my trys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work:

```
def get_collatz(n):
    i=1
    while True:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n /= 2
        else:
            n = 3 * n + 1
        if n == 1:
            return(i)
        i += 1
        
for i in range(1, 100000):
    print(i, get_collatz(i))
```

If you want to know the number that took most steps, you can do this:

```
steps = dict()
for i in range(1, 100000):
    steps[i] = get_collatz(i)

n_max = max(steps, key=steps.get)
total_steps = steps[n_max]
print(f'Number {n_max} took {total_steps} steps to reach 1.')
```

This prints:

```
Number 77031 took 350 steps to reach 1.
```

You can also create a sorted dictionary:

```
sorted_steps = dict(sorted(steps.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]))
```

Comment: thanks but as I said for one number it works for me.

Comment: I just realised you wanted to see the value for all numbers. Updated the code to show you the number of steps for each number.

Comment: I think the other answer is printing the wrong numbers, according with Collatz conjecture. But anyways, choose what suits you best.

Comment: you're right, it prints the first operation only.

Comment: i'll be happy for another help, now I want to find the largest number in get_collatz(i), how can I sort it?

Comment: See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `range()` you get a list of numbers in that range. Did you mean `number` instead of `Collatz` because in the for loop you are looping through the `Collatz` and the value is in `number`. And while loop isn't doing anything so I recommend removing it.

Use this code:

```
Collatz = range(1, 1001)
counting = 0
for number in Collatz:
    if number % 2 == 0:
        number = int(number / 2)
        print(number)
        counting += 1
    else:
        number = int(number * 3 + 1)
        print(number)
        counting += 1
print(counting)
```

Comment: thanks but it returns an error too.

Comment: I edited my answer, try this code now. Is that what you want?

Comment: as @LeonardoVaz says, it prints the first operation only.